# Is it possible to provision a model with a generic type as a property?

Tags: c#, generics

## Background

I have a few dozen models and for each I have built a search & filter method that returns a filtered list of that model.  I use this method for a web project and return the resulting list via WebApi to the view (as JSON).

I would like to create a model that includes the list of results along with an `int` property representing the total count of results found on the server side (if you take paging into account, I will only return a subset of the found results to the view).

## Question

Is it possible to create generic response model like this:

```
public class FilteredResultModel
{
    public List<T> Results { get; set; }
    public int TotalResultsFound{ get; set; }
}
```

Or do I need to create a separate result model for each type of model I search and filter:

```
public class FilteredCatResultModel
    {
        public List<Cat> Results { get; set; }
        public int TotalResultsFound{ get; set; }
    }

public class FilteredDogResultModel
    {
        public List<Dog> Results { get; set; }
        public int TotalResultsFound{ get; set; }
    }
```

If it is possible, how would it be accomplished?

## SOLVED!

Thanks to Dmitry and others below in the comments, this is solved:

```
public class FilteredResultModel<T> //<----(added the <T>)
{
    public List<T> Results { get; set; }
    public int TotalResultsFound{ get; set; }
}
```

Example implementation:

```
var resultModel = FilteredResultModel<Dog>
            {
                Count = 4000,
                Results = new List<Dog>();
            };
```

Comment: Why not just `FilteredResultModel<T>`?

Comment: Unless the classes are supposed to provide additional functionality beyond what you have here, you might as well return a List<T> or ReadOnlyCollection<T>.

Comment: @Dmitry--Can you please elaborate on how that would work?  Nevermind--I think I see now. . .

Comment: Yes that exactly what I have done in one of my web api projects,  and in each web api I get the total of my search results,  and return the selected results page.  So yes thats totally fine.

Comment: `FilteredResultModel<T>` works perfectly, thanks gents.  @Dmitry, would you care to enter the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the `<T>` to the class name:

```
public class FilteredResultModel<T>
{
    public List<T> Results { get; set; }
    public int TotalResultsFound{ get; set; }
}
```